# Why Relational tables via Laravel migrations created with MyISAM which don't support relational features

Tags: laravel, relational-database, innodb, myisam

I noticed, Laravel creates tables via storage engine as MyISAM which does not support relational features.

I have setup the foreign keys via migrations but when I checked in Phpmyadmin, it shows no relational features due to storage engine being MyISAM.

I have read that if I change to InnoDB the relationships can be applied.

But my question is if I cannot add relationships, then why Laravel took that storage engine as MyISAM ?
Is there no need to put relationships in database ?? That would make my database vulnerable.

What is the best practice as per Laravel ?

Comment: Best practice for MySQL is to use InnoDB, not MyISAM.  Period.  Full stop.  If Laravel wants to use MyISAM, don't use Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was not necessarily Laravel that made the database tables MyISAM. If you do not specify it, the tables will be created using the default storage engine of your MySQL version/installation. In your case it was probably MyISAM.
To ensure InnoDB is used, edit your config/database.php file and set
'engine' => 'InnoDB',